# Material Design Lite and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, material-design, material-design-lite

I want to add a new slider component of MDL library by using JS.
When I define the slider component in the HTML the component is correctly loaded but when I try to add it by using javascript the style isn't applied to the slider.
Why is it happening? 
Library Link : https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#sliders-section
I saw on the main page that there is a special way to dynamically show components, but I didn't get how does it work.
Link : https://getmdl.io/started/index.html

```js
function create()
{
  
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.className = "mdl-slider mdl-js-slider";
  element.setAttribute("type","range");
  element.setAttribute("min","0");
  element.setAttribute("value","0");
  element.setAttribute("max","100");
  element.setAttribute("tabindex","0");
  
  document.getElementById("c").appendChild(element);

}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="c">
<input class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" type="range"  min="0" max="100" value="0" tabindex="0">
<button onclick="create()">Click me</button>
</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: It works in your snippet. What's the problem?

Comment: When I click on the "click me" button a new slider is added but it isn't the same as the first one, the style is different

Comment: FYI MDL is legacy. The current UI project is [MDC-Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web).

Answer (score 2):

When dynamically creating elements with MDL, you need to *register* new elements using the `upgradeElement` function. In your particular case, your code would look something like this:

```
function create()
{  
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.className = "mdl-slider mdl-js-slider";
  element.setAttribute("type","range");
  element.setAttribute("min","0");
  element.setAttribute("value","0");
  element.setAttribute("max","100");
  element.setAttribute("tabindex","0");  
  document.getElementById("c").appendChild(element);

  componentHandler.upgradeElement(element); // <--- Note the MDL element registration
}
```

**[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEbjpp)**

Applicable portion of the [Material Design Lite Documentation](https://getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic):

> Material Design Lite will automatically register and render all
>   elements marked with MDL classes upon page load. However in the case
>   where you are creating DOM elements dynamically you need to register
>   new elements using the `upgradeElement` function.